# Intel MKL Sparse QR Solve in C++ returns not initialized error

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

When attempting to use `mkl_sparse_s_qr_solve`, I receive a result of all 0's and the error status of `SPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED` which means that the handle/matrix is empty.

I have tried reading through the documentation thoroughly and printing all arrays that are used to instantiate the CSR sparse matrix required for the solve, and all the arrays contain the correct values.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> i_b(22);
    std::vector<int> i_e(22);
    // j, v, and b vectors are just examples.
    // Regardless of the resulting numbers of the solve, I just
    // cannot get the SPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED error to stop
    // for the qr solver.
    std::vector<int> j(44, 0);
    std::vector<float> v(44, 1.0);
    std::vector<float> b(22, 1.0);

    {
        struct IncGenerator {
            int current_;
            IncGenerator(int start) : current_(start) {}
            int operator() () {
                current_ += 2;
                return current_;
            }
        };
        // Fill i_b with {0, 2, 4, ..., 42}
        IncGenerator g(-2);
        std::generate(i_b.begin(), i_b.end(), g);

        // Fill i_e with {2, 4, 6, ..., 44}
        IncGenerator f(0);
        std::generate(i_e.begin(), i_e.end(), f);
    }

    // ...

    // j, v, and b arrays are all the correct values
    // confirmed. The sparse A matrix should have 2 values
    // per row, with 22 rows, and 15 columns.

    int out;
    sparse_matrix_t A;
    out = mkl_sparse_s_create_csr(&A, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO, 22, 15, &i_b[0], &i_e[0], &j[0], &v[0]);

    switch (out) {
    case SPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        std::cout << "Successfully created matrix!" << std::endl;
        break;
    case SPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        std::cout << "Not initialized." << std::endl;
        break;
    case SPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        std::cout << "Internal memory allocation failed." << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    std::vector<float> X(22 * 15);
    out = mkl_sparse_s_qr_solve(SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, A, NULL, SPARSE_LAYOUT_COLUMN_MAJOR, 1, &X[0], 15, &asv[0], 22);
    switch (out) {
    case SPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        std::cout << "Successfully solved!" << std::endl;
        break;
    case SPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        std::cout << "Not initialized." << std::endl;
        break;
    case SPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        std::cout << "Internal memory allocation failed." << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Unknown." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, for some reason I cannot solve with `A` because it either thinks A is empty or something else is uninitialized. I do not think `A` is empty (I wanted to check but there was no convenient way to print `A`) as the initialization of the matrix `A` returns as a successful operation (the only thing I am slightly doubtful of is the row beginning `i_b` and row end `i_e` indices).

Can anyone please offer some guidance?

Comment: PLatform? Compiler?

Comment: Windows, visual studio 2019.

Comment: From the horse mouth: "Supported C/C++ and Fortran compilers for Windows - Microsoft Visual Studio 2017"

Comment: Strange, the 2019 version update 4 of MKL provides integration with Visual Studio 2019 while update 3 does not, and I used update 4. Doesn't seem like a lack of support. Not to mention, everything compiled and ran.

Comment: Technically, it might work because MS stated they're binary compatible between VC++ 142 (from VS 2019) and VC++ 141 (VS2017). BUt I would advice to try to use v141 compiler in the project and see if it helps

Comment: Ah I see, I'll give that a shot and post back here! Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I mean, you could set to use v141 right from VS2019, don't need to install VS2017

Comment: Ah yes, that's a typo. Whoops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you are supposed to use `mkl_sparse_?_qr_solve`. Sparse systems are solved in 3 steps (phases):

1. Reorder.
2. Factorize.
3. Solve.

First, you have to call `mkl_sparse_qr_reorder`, then `mkl_sparse_?_qr_factorize`, and only then `mkl_sparse_?_qr_solve`:

Try to insert the following code before `mkl_sparse_?_qr_solve`:

```
struct matrix_descr descr;
descr.type = SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL;
out = mkl_sparse_qr_reorder(A, descr);
switch (out) { ... }

out = mkl_sparse_?_qr_factorize(A, NULL);
switch (out) { ... }
```

Or just use `mkl_sparse_?_qr` that will do all 3 steps for you in a single call. Separation of the process into three steps gives you more freedom. For example, if you want to solve several systems with the same `A`, you can save time by calling `mkl_sparse_qr_reorder` and `mkl_sparse_?_qr_factorize` only once.

Not directly related, but don't use `int` instead of `MKL_INT`. When `MKL_ILP64` is defined, `MKL_INT` is not `int`, but `long long int`.

Comment: Ah I see, I’ll try that out now. Thank you! I had no idea.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much! (As an aside also had to change a bit with the row indices)